# Facebook Canvas Page Redirect

Tags: facebook, redirect

I am currently building a Facebook app but am having some issues with the canvas page. When I click on my app on Facebook, it loads my canvas page url which is 'http://apps.facebook.com/"App NameSpace"'. When the page loads, the text "invalid credentials" is displayed and the page redirects to http://app_name.herokuapp.com/ where my app is displayed and is functional. Why is this redirection occurring and how can I make my app load in the canvas page http://apps.facebook.com/"App NameSpace" ?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems some problem with your permissions try to use this

facebook official [permissions doc](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/)